# Perl::Tidy to minify Perl code

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

I am trying to use [Perl::Tidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/lib/Perl/Tidy.pod) module to minify Perl code as much as possible. I do not care about formatting of course, so I am setting the argv manually for the module. One issue that I am unable to figure out is the space on the sides of the "=" sign and the arrow "=>" it adjusts it to vertical tabs. If I use the switch "-naws" it removes all spaces and keywords stick to the variables etc.

Below is a sample test script with Perl tidy options for quick review.

```
use Perl::Tidy;

my $source_string = <<'EOT';
# this is comment remove it

=another pod
also remove this pod line
=cut

my $error = Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
    argv        => $argv,
    source      => \$source_string,
    destination => \$dest_string,
    stderr      => \$stderr_string,
    errorfile   => \$errorfile_string,
);
sub {
    my (@arg) = @_;
    print @arg;
    foreach my $var (@items) {
        print "my name is $item" or die "error here";
    }
    return;

    if ($names) {
        say "ok";
    } else {
        print "nice";
    }
    $name = $x + 123 + $year . $month;

    our @EXPORT = (
        Moose => [],
        utf8  => [],
        #true => [],
    );

    }
EOT

my $dest_string;
my $stderr_string;
my $errorfile_string;

my $argv = "-npro";    # Ignore any .perltidyrc at this site

$argv .= " -pbp";                        # Format according to perl best practices
$argv .= " -nst";                        # Must turn off -st in case -pbp is specified
$argv .= " -se";                         # -se appends the errorfile to stderr
$argv .= " -ci=0 -cti=0 -dac -sil=0";    #

$argv
    = "-vt=2 -nolq -i=0 -sil=0 -ce -l=1024 -nbl -pt=2 -bt=2 -sbt=2 -bbt=2 -bvt=2 -sbvt=1 -pvtc=1 -cti=0 -ci=0 -nsfs -nsts -bar -dac -dbc -dsc -dp -sob -ce -mbl=0 -dws -ple ";
#$argv .= " -wbb='% + - * / x != == >= <= =~ !~ < > | & = **= += *= &= <<= &&= -= /= |= >>= ||= //= .= %= ^= x=' "; # want break before tokens in string
#$argv .= " -nsak='my our local' -naws    ";
$argv .= " -aws -nsfs -nolq";    # default -aws is on, off = -naws

my $error = Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
    argv        => $argv,
    source      => \$source_string,
    destination => \$dest_string,
    stderr      => \$stderr_string,
    errorfile   => \$errorfile_string,    # ignored when -se flag is set
);

if ($error) {
    # serious error in input parameters, no tidied output
    die "Exiting because of serious errors -dac -sil=0\n";
}

if ($dest_string) { print "\n$dest_string\n" }
#if ($stderr_string)    { print "<<STDERR>>\n$stderr_string\n" }
#if ($errorfile_string) { print "<<.ERR file>>\n$errorfile_string\n" }

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

=Tidy Options

http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/perltidy.html

These are Perl::Tidy module options that can be passed in the $argv variable 
to the ProcessPerlFile sub routine.

Negates:

A prefix of "n" negates short form toggle switches, and a prefix of "no"
negates the long forms. For example, -nasc means don't add missing
semicolons.  

Basic Options

 -i=n    use n columns per indentation level (default n=4)
 -t      tabs: use one tab character per indentation level, not recommeded
 -nt     no tabs: use n spaces per indentation level (default)
 -et=n   entab leading whitespace n spaces per tab; not recommended
 -io     "indent only": just do indentation, no other formatting.
 -sil=n  set starting indentation level to n;  use if auto detection fails
 -ole=s  specify output line ending (s=dos or win, mac, unix)
 -ple    keep output line endings same as input (input must be filename)

Whitespace Control

 -fws    freeze whitespace; this disables all whitespace changes
           and disables the following switches: 
 -bt=n   sets brace tightness,  n= (0 = loose, 1=default, 2 = tight)
 -bbt    same as -bt but for code block braces; same as -bt if not given
 -bbvt   block braces vertically tight; use with -bl or -bli
 -bbvtl=s  make -bbvt to apply to selected list of block types
 -pt=n   paren tightness (n=0, 1 or 2)
 -sbt=n  square bracket tightness (n=0, 1, or 2)
 -bvt=n  brace vertical tightness, 
         n=(0=open, 1=close unless multiple steps on a line, 2=always close)
 -pvt=n  paren vertical tightness (see -bvt for n)
 -sbvt=n square bracket vertical tightness (see -bvt for n)
 -bvtc=n closing brace vertical tightness: 
         n=(0=open, 1=sometimes close, 2=always close)
 -pvtc=n closing paren vertical tightness, see -bvtc for n.
 -sbvtc=n closing square bracket vertical tightness, see -bvtc for n.
 -ci=n   sets continuation indentation=n,  default is n=2 spaces
 -lp     line up parentheses, brackets, and non-BLOCK braces
 -sfs    add space before semicolon in for( ; ; )
 -aws    allow perltidy to add whitespace (default)
 -dws    delete all old non-essential whitespace 
 -icb    indent closing brace of a code block
 -cti=n  closing indentation of paren, square bracket, or non-block brace: 
         n=0 none, =1 align with opening, =2 one full indentation level
 -icp    equivalent to -cti=2
 -wls=s  want space left of tokens in string; i.e. -nwls='+ - * /'
 -wrs=s  want space right of tokens in string;
 -sts    put space before terminal semicolon of a statement
 -sak=s  put space between keywords given in s and '(';
 -nsak=s no space between keywords in s and '('; i.e. -nsak='my our local'

Line Break Control

 -fnl    freeze newlines; this disables all line break changes
            and disables the following switches:
 -anl    add newlines;  ok to introduce new line breaks
 -bbs    add blank line before subs and packages
 -bbc    add blank line before block comments
 -bbb    add blank line between major blocks
 -sob    swallow optional blank lines
 -ce     cuddled else; use this style: '} else {'
 -dnl    delete old newlines (default)
 -mbl=n  maximum consecutive blank lines (default=1)
 -l=n    maximum line length;  default n=80
 -bl     opening brace on new line 
 -sbl    opening sub brace on new line.  value of -bl is used if not given.
 -bli    opening brace on new line and indented
 -bar    opening brace always on right, even for long clauses
 -vt=n   vertical tightness (requires -lp); n controls break after opening
         token: 0=never  1=no break if next line balanced   2=no break
 -vtc=n  vertical tightness of closing container; n controls if closing
         token starts new line: 0=always  1=not unless list  1=never
 -wba=s  want break after tokens in string; i.e. wba=': .'
 -wbb=s  want break before tokens in string

Following Old Breakpoints

 -boc    break at old comma breaks: turns off all automatic list formatting
 -bol    break at old logical breakpoints: or, and, ||, && (default)
 -bok    break at old list keyword breakpoints such as map, sort (default)
 -bot    break at old conditional (trinary ?:) operator breakpoints (default)
 -cab=n  break at commas after a comma-arrow (=>):
         n=0 break at all commas after =>
         n=1 stable: break unless this breaks an existing one-line container
         n=2 break only if a one-line container cannot be formed
         n=3 do not treat commas after => specially at all

Comment controls

 -ibc    indent block comments (default)
 -isbc   indent spaced block comments; may indent unless no leading space
 -msc=n  minimum desired spaces to side comment, default 4
 -csc    add or update closing side comments after closing BLOCK brace
 -dcsc   delete closing side comments created by a -csc command
 -cscp=s change closing side comment prefix to be other than '## end'
 -cscl=s change closing side comment to apply to selected list of blocks
 -csci=n minimum number of lines needed to apply a -csc tag, default n=6
 -csct=n maximum number of columns of appended text, default n=20 
 -cscw   causes warning if old side comment is overwritten with -csc

 -sbc    use 'static block comments' identified by leading '##' (default)
 -sbcp=s change static block comment identifier to be other than '##'
 -osbc   outdent static block comments

 -ssc    use 'static side comments' identified by leading '##' (default)
 -sscp=s change static side comment identifier to be other than '##'

Delete selected text

 -dac    delete all comments AND pod
 -dbc    delete block comments     
 -dsc    delete side comments  
 -dp     delete pod

Send selected text to a '.TEE' file

 -tac    tee all comments AND pod
 -tbc    tee block comments       
 -tsc    tee side comments       
 -tp     tee pod           

Outdenting

 -olq    outdent long quoted strings (default) 
 -olc    outdent a long block comment line
 -ola    outdent statement labels
 -okw    outdent control keywords (redo, next, last, goto, return)
 -okwl=s specify alternative keywords for -okw command

Other controls

 -mft=n  maximum fields per table; default n=40
 -x      do not format lines before hash-bang line (i.e., for VMS)
 -asc    allows perltidy to add a ';' when missing (default)
 -dsm    allows perltidy to delete an unnecessary ';'  (default)

Combinations of other parameters

 -gnu     attempt to follow GNU Coding Standards as applied to perl
 -mangle  remove as many newlines as possible (but keep comments and pods)
 -extrude  insert as many newlines as possible

Dump and die, debugging

 -dop    dump options used in this run to standard output and quit
 -ddf    dump default options to standard output and quit
 -dsn    dump all option short names to standard output and quit
 -dln    dump option long names to standard output and quit
 -dpro   dump whatever configuRatio file is in effect to standard output
 -dtt    dump all token types to standard output and quit

HTML

 -html write an html file (see 'man perl2web' for many options)
       Note: when -html is used, no indentation or formatting are done.
       Hint: try perltidy -html -css=mystyle.css filename.pl
       and edit mystyle.css to change the appearance of filename.html.
       -nnn gives line numbers
       -pre only writes out <pre>..</pre> code section
       -toc places a table of contents to subs at the top (default)
       -pod passes pod text through pod2html (default)
       -frm write html as a frame (3 files)
       -text=s extra extension for table of contents if -frm, default='toc'
       -sext=s extra extension for file content if -frm, default='src'

Perltidy home page at http://perltidy.sourceforge.net
=cut

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and below is the minified code.

```
my $error = Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
argv        => $argv,
source      => \$source_string,
destination => \$dest_string,
stderr      => \$stderr_string,
errorfile   => \$errorfile_string,);
sub {
my (@arg) = @_;
print @arg;
foreach my $var (@items) {
print "my name is $item" or die "error here";
}
return;
if ($names) {
say "ok";
} else {
print "nice";
}
$name = $x + 123 + $year . $month;
our @EXPORT = (
Moose => [],
utf8  => [],);
}
```

So I still want to remove spaces similar to below lines:

```
my $error = Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
argv        => $argv,
# ... );

sub {
my (@arg) = @_;
```

to become:

```
my $error=Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
argv=>$argv,
# ... );

sub{
my(@arg)=@_;
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your last and second to last code blocks. You should add some ommission comments there, it's very confusing and I don't think you would want to minify your code by removing half of it and make it invalid.;)

Comment: Modified the last two code blocks for more clarity.

Comment: It's still wrong. ;)

Comment: Why you just modify it the way you see it?

Comment: Because editing code in a post to change behaviour is discouraged. I did it now. Minor change, but helpful to readers I think.

Comment: I'm interested in your use-case for this?

Comment: @Peter R Simply I minify the entire application before sending to the customers website saving average 30-50% of the entire app size which also saves time on loading and parsing the Perl code. Also I minify the installed Perl version on the server to have the same goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove spaces around `=` and `=>` you need to use the `-nwls`/`--nowant-left-space` and `--nwrs`/`--nowant-right-space` options:

```
-nwls="= =>" -nwrs="= =>"
```